Is there any way to add customisability to updateOn in angular forms?
Let me explain myself. I have some async validator in my form that checks something in the database. This check is costly. Thus, I'm obviously unable to use the "change" parameter in updateOn, because that would imply a lot of useless requests being made.
I switched to "focus" for my use case, but sometimes my form just has one entry, and it's not ergonomic for the user to click somewhere else random before beeing able to click on the send button (that is disabled as long as the form is not validated btw).
I know I can validate on form submit, but it does not exactly match what I want to do.
Isn't there a way to have a custom "updateOn" that would trigger only when the user stops typing for x ms (for example) ? Is there even a solution ?
I obviously read the documentation of the real updateOn parameter for FormControls, and realized it does not allow for anything custom. Not knowing the alternatives to this or how I can achieve my goal, this is why I'm asking.
Thank you a lot for your answers.

I did not know about debounce until just now, thank you a lot !
